# Why do Nintendo 3DS games have 17 pins?

Tags: hardware, pins

I took a good, hard look at one of my Nintendo 3DS games today, and I realized that there are actually 17 pins on the game that connect with the console. Why? I was under the impression that "everything" needed to be to a power of 2?

Comment: Why would it need to be a power of 2?

Comment: Because 16 would be too few and 18 would be too many.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Programming-wise the nearest data sizes would be something like an int16 or an int32. What's the point of the extra pin?

Comment: Uh... power? Paging selects?

Comment: You weren't wrong in thinking it is based on powers of two, but were mixed up as to what would be.  Think of the number of pins as the *exponent*, ie, 2-to-the-what (minus those used for power and ground and strobes and all that).

Comment: you need more than just data lines to talk to a device, you need power and ground (and maybe a few grounds for signal vs power ground) and potentially some clock or addressing lines.

Comment: Maybe not all pins are data pins. There may be ground and power pins in there. There may be a few ground and, say, 3V3, 5V (that's 3 pins instead of 1, 2 or 4 right there.) Plus some data pins. Even the data pins can be split into groups.

Comment: There could be a 8-bit parallel data bus, a serial bus or two, multiple power pins (3.3V, 5V, ground), things like enable/ready/clock signals, a hot-swap-ready pin perhaps, to tell the main processor that all power signals are correctly in place, among many other possible signals that the designers chose to put in their game cartridges.

Comment: OP doesn't unerstand how something works, asks us about it, and we downvote the question to hell without answering and correcting their faulty understanding of the underlying electronic engineering? **WTF**

Comment: @Passerby we are within our right to do this, as it IS 'shows little research effort' and 'is not useful' at all.

Comment: How does it show little research effort? My programming background has always taught me things work in powers of 2. Seeing 17 is very unusual to me.

Comment: @kyranF and I am within my right to point out how flawed and stupid that is. op does show an understanding, and signs of research. But OP isn't a god, and the info he has gave him the wrong conclusion. Which is why he reached out here to ask us to help fix that wrong conclusion! So again ***WTF***.

Comment: Kyle Baran: the real world is not nicely ordered into lots of 2^x, there is a lot more going on. The number of wires does not need to line up with data structures which are entirely software/digital based. @Passerby A question like this perhaps should be asked in the Chat? The OP seems to have done no research into possible uses for 17 pins in an embedded system..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because its answer requires speculation without inside knowledge of the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digital Data, based on its nature of binary states, is a power of 2. While this is still true for hardware, there is lots of overlap. Any given digital signal will have two wires/pins involved, the signal and a reference. That reference pin is normally Ground. But a single Ground pin can work for multiple signals.

The 3DS has 17 pins because of need. Some of these are also serve multiple purposes. From http://3dbrew.org/wiki/Gamecards
[image]

There is a single power source, multiple Ground pins, 8 data pins (shared, 8 bit parallel bus for the Rom, and 3/4 pins for the serial bus SPI eeprom), a reset pin, a Interrupt/Removal pin (if you pull the cart out or if its not there at boot), a Clock pin, and a pair of Chip Selects. Finally a Not-Connected pin, likely for debug or factory purposes.

For the most part, all of these pins are referenced to ground, and they are Powers of 2, because their outputs are binary. Remember, a 2^1 is still a power of 2.

Answer (score 2):

[ This started as a comment, but I've run out of room.
Apologies for posting this historical anecdote as an answer.
Feel free to flag into oblivion. ]

**Legend**
[Von Karman (1881–1963)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_von_K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n) - the man who went on to become one of the great aerodynamicists of the XX century - was in a logistics transport regiment in the Austro-Hungarian army during World War One.  When an Austrian royal prince was inspecting his regiment, he wanted to demonstrate interest in technology.  Allegedly, the following dialogue took place.

Prince, pointing at a new lorry:  "Does it have a 6-cylinder engine?"
Von Karman:  "Yes, your Highness."
P:  "Is this a 4-stroke engine?"
K:  "Yes, this a 4-stroke, your Highness."
P:  "How can a 4-stroke engine have 6 cylinders?"
K:  "Your Highness, the remaining 2 cylinders are spares."

**update:**  Found [another significantly different version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archduke_Joseph_Ferdinand_of_Austria#World_War_I) of the same story.